# mocking subprocess Process terminate

Tags: python, unit-testing

I couldn't find a question exactly like this one. I'm having difficulty understanding how to mock out the returned value of subprocess.Popen so that I can validate terminate was called when I try to stop it. The server.py class looks like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

class Server(object):

    def start(self):
        devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', 'import time; time.sleep(10);print "This message should not appear"'], stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)

    def stop(self):
        if self.proc:
            self.proc.terminate()
```

My test class looks like this. I want to know that terminate was called when stop was called but when I run the test with nose it says that terminate was called 0 times. My understanding of patch is that it replaces the implementation of subprocess.Popen and also all available methods.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from server import Server
from mock import patch, MagicMock, Mock

class ServerTest(TestCase):

    @patch("subprocess.Popen")
    @patch('__builtin__.open')
    def test_stop_when_running(self, mock_open, mock_subprocess):
        server = Server()
        server.start()
        server.stop()
        mock_subprocess.terminate.assert_called_once_with()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the `Popen` that's actually used by the code that you're testing. So the patch path would be:

```
@patch("server.subprocess.Popen")
@patch('server.__builtin__.open')
def test_stop_when_running(self, mock_open, mock_subprocess):
    server = Server()
    server.start()
    server.stop()
    mock_subprocess.terminate.assert_called_once_with()
```

However, `terminate` is called on the return value of `subprocess.Popen()` so it would need to become:

```
mock_subprocess.return_value.terminate.assert_called_once_with()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`server.proc.terminate.assert_called_once_with()`